# Can I edit the staging area in Git directly?

Tags: git

Are the staged files in Git stored somewhere so that I can edit them manually, without using Git commands? For example, can I open staged files in an editor and change what is staged, or delete entire files that are staged or add new ones (if I want to make files be deleted or added in the next commit), without changing modifying my working directory?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. You can just unstage a file you want to edit and then stage it again after modifying.

Comment: It's possible to "edit" the staging area without touching the working directory. But you still need git commands. The staging area involves `.git/index` and `.git/objects/`. These files have special internal formats. It's very hard to manually edit unless you are very familiar with the formats and able to edit binary data.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the reason you wish to do this?

Comment: @TTT If I have made a lot of edits to my codebase and want to commit those changes incrementally, I may sometimes need to make temporary changes (and commit those) to the staging area that don't exist in my working directory, to prevent breaking the code, which would be easier to do if I could work on the staging area files directly.

Answer (score 3):

> Are the staged files in Git stored somewhere

Yes, in `.git/objects` where the entire repository is stored. Locally-added new content starts out lightly compressed and internally type-tagged in `.git/objects/??` where `??` is the first two digits of its id, and the filename in that directory is the rest of the id.

> so that I can edit them manually, without using Git commands?

No. The git repository is a content-addressable database, different content has a different id.  What you *can* do is what all the editor plugins that let you edit staged files do: use any equivalent of `git cat-file -p :path/to/file` to decompress the content staged at that path somewhere handy, edit it as you please, then some equivalent of (keyboard-to-editbox warning) `git update-index --cacheinfo 100644,$(git hash-object -w --path path/to/file somewhere.handy),path/to/file` to add the edited content to the repo and update the index entry.

> For example, can I open staged files in an editor and change what is staged, or delete entire files that are staged or add new ones (if I want to make files be deleted or added in the next commit), without changing modifying my working directory?

As mentioned above, every decent editor has plugins that already do the above ritual to accomplish exactly this, and for people stuck without a decent editor plugin there's `git gui` which comes with Git and does the same thing but less wonderfully than a real editor could.

Answer (score 1):

No, or at least not easily. Staged files are stored in format your editor would not understand - see for yourself in `.git/index` and `.git/objects`. Consider staging index a format internal to Git and manipulate it only with Git client (be it command line client or some library).

Comment: Unlike some other versioning systems, git does not store diffs; it stores each file as a snapshot under a hashed name. I.e. if you change one line in a 2Mb file and commit both versions, you will have two 2Mb git objects (if they don't get compressed).

Comment: @Amadan You're confusing what Git presents to its users with what it does internally. Git's internal diffs are not done against a fixed base, they're done against as much history as Git's been configured to inspect, which for madeupnumber95%+ of all projects is "all of it", and they're not done onesie-twosie, they're done in a big batch when it looks like really gratifying compression wins are available. This is why for instance my entire Linux history is 2.2G: Git's not trying to use grossly limited inter-version diffs for storage compression.

Comment: @jthill You misunderstood what I said. Sure, in packfiles, delta-based compression is used; but the basic operation of git, on files that are being actively worked on, and especially on the staged files, stores entire files as blobs, not as diffs. The answer originally said staged files are stored as diffs, which is not true; this part is now removed.

Comment: @jthill I believe what Amadan commented was right. I originally phrased my answer as if staged snapshot is diff which indeed is not true. I edited the answer since.

Comment: It's right so far as it goes but it's so incomplete as to be misleading, for instance both you and Amadan were misled into inferred that staging has something to do with (re)packing. It doesn't. New staged do start out individually compressed but can be packed at any time. It's just the marginal benefits of waiting exceed the marginal benefits of pulling the repack trigger for a lot longer than people first expect, so Git defaults to just letting a lot of them accumulate before repacking. Which isn't necessarily done at a commit boundary.